# How can I use iSAM in ROS

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I plan to apply [iSAM algorithm](https://borg.cc.gatech.edu/download) for location by using an AMP2.5 with a GPS connected. Hence the inputs are angular velocities and linear accelerates from IMU, and positions from GPS.

However, I do not know how to include the GTSAM package in my ROS code, neither do I know how to compile and execute.

Could anyone give me some hints? Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220399/how-can-i-use-isam-in-ros/) by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2015-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

In my case, I included iSAM library in my ROS package.

I created a new package, with catkin_creat_package, and add the following lines to the CMake file

```
add_executable(my_node src/my_node.cpp   )
target_link_libraries(my_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} isam cholmod)
add_dependencies(my_node my_package)
```

I installed iSAM library on /usr/include.

---

Originally posted by [DanROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25046/danros/) with karma: 18 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0